# Can't call function php, ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use Ajax to get access to my comment_insert.php. In my comment_insert.php i want to call a public static function thats located in another php file(`comments_pasta.php`). If i call the function, my program gets an

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "

And if i delete the call, everything works fine. I'm new to ajax.

```
function comment_post_btn_click(){

    var _comment = $('#comment-post-text').val();
    var _userId = $('#userId').val();
    var _userName = $('#userName').val();

    if(_comment.length > 0 && _userId != null){
        console.log(_comment + " " + _userName + " " +_userId);

        $.post("/ajax/comment_insert.php",
            {
                //we use this in the comment_insert.php(AJAX)
                task : "comment_insert",
                userId : _userId,
                comment : _comment
            }   

        ).success(
            function(data){
                //going to turn the Json from comment_insert.php(AJAX)into a javascript object
                comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
                console.log("Response text = " + data);


<?php 

    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'comment_insert' ){

        require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'defines.php';

        $userId = (int)$_POST['userId'];
        $comment = addslashes(str_replace ("\n" , "<br>" , $_POST['comment']));

        $std = new stdClass();

        $std -> userId = $userId;
        $std -> comment = $comment;
        $std -> userName = $_SESSION['userName'];

        require_once ('comments_pasta.php');


        Talk:hej();



        echo json_encode($std);
    }

?>

<?php

class Talk{

    public static function hej(){
        console.log("HEJ");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You've got a javascript console command in PHP... That's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that the unexpected syntax error is actually because PHP is throwing an error, and it's formatted error reporting contains something like `<p> There was an error! </p>` and it breaks on the `<` which also coincidentally invalides your `JSON` response to the script. `console.log()` is a javascript function. You cannot execute that in PHP.

What you actually should do is `echo` or `return` that variable and assign it to your object.

```
public static function hej(){
   return "HEJ":
}
```

Then in your PHP script.

```
$std -> userName = $_SESSION['userName'];

require_once ('comments_pasta.php');

$std->HEJ = Talk:hej();
```

Now you can do `console.log(data.HEJ)` in your `success` function of your `$.post()` wrapper.

Furthermore, you are doing `comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));` however, you can have jQuery automatically parse the returned data in the `$.post()` wrapper by adding `'json'` as the final argument to the call, please observe:

```
$.post({ //object

}, 'json'); // <--final line closing $.post() wrapper
```

And now it's just:

```
comment_insert(data);
```

This should resolve it.

Comment: thanks for the answer! can you show me where i should add the  'json'); in my code.

Answer (score 0):

try this ajax call

```
function comment_post_btn_click()
    {


var _comment  = $('#comment-post-text').val();
var _userId   = $('#userId').val();
var _userName = $('#userName').val();


        var form_data   =   new FormData();                  

        form_data.append('_comment',_comment);
        form_data.append('_userId',_userId);
        form_data.append('_userName',_userName);


        $.ajax({
                // url          :   'userListAjax.php?r='+Math.random();,
                url         :   'userListAjax.php?r=',
                dataType    :   'text',
                cache       :   false,
                contentType :   false,
                processData :   false,
                data        :   form_data,                       
                // data: {params:[page,display]},                         
                type        :   'post',
                success     :   function(data){
                    // alert(data);
                    document.getElementById("dynamicContent").innerHTML=data;

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

well nothing works.. to get the output from comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data)); i simply need to delete the call of the function. if i do a console.log("Response text = " + data); before the comment_insert with the function call i get this:

Response text = 

( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant console - assumed 'console' in C:\wamp\www\ajax\comments_pasta.php on line *7*
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0000247944{main}(  )..\comment_insert.php**:**0
20.0120262616Talk::hej(  )..\comment_insert.php**:**20



( ! ) Warning: log() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in C:\wamp\www\ajax\comments_pasta.php on line *7*
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0000247944{main}(  )..\comment_insert.php**:**0
20.0120262616Talk::hej(  )..\comment_insert.php**:**20
30.0210263032http://www.php.net/function.log' target='_new'>log
(  )..\comments_pasta.php**:**7

{"userId":1,"comment":"test commenttext","userName":"alex"}

and if i delete the function call i get what i want in the console.log:

asdasd Alexander Lundh 1 comment_insert.js:18
Response text = {"userId":1,"comment":"asdasd","userName":"alex"}